# addons.mozilla.org validation shows compile-time error in the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

Note:addons works correctly but getting error in firefox validation addon website https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/addon/validate

**my code**

```
panel.port.on("changing_now_speed_val", function (speed) {

    var com = 'document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate='+speed + ';';
    tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScript: com
    });
});
```

**Error**
while testing on it says

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/addon/validate

Extension Tests

JavaScript Compile-Time Error

Warning: A compile-time error in the JavaScript halted validation of that file.

Message: expected expression, got ';
resources/html5_youtube_video_speed_controller/lib/main.js
```

[image: warning pic]

But addons works correctly

Comment: Probably your code should be checking to make sure `speed` is not empty. If it is, that line of code you're adding will be invalid.

Comment: it is not,addons works correctly but getting error in firefox validation addon website only

Comment: Well that error you're getting is exactly what would happen if that "changing_now_speed_val" handler were invoked with something like an empty string as the value of `speed`.

Comment: ,addons works correctly,i just getting warning when i submit to addons.mozilla.org  and do you think it is just validation bug of somekind

Comment: I guess so; if your code seems to do what you want, then that's what counts I think.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/youtubevideospeedcontroller/

Comment: my addon was accepted , i try it before and it was not accepted thank you can you find out how to fix warning and i think  contentScript: com is giving the warning

Comment: i think  contentScript: com is giving the warning alternate way to this is to use contentScriptFile(as iook around in google,mozilla doc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Loading_Content_Scripts

"Unless your content script is extremely simple and consists only of a static string, don't use contentScript: if you do, you may have problems getting your add-on approved on AMO.

Instead, keep the script in a separate file and load it using contentScriptFile. This makes your code easier to maintain, secure, debug and review"

**There is more info there:**

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1185355

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
panel.port.on("changing_now_speed_val", function (speed) {

    speed = speed || 1;
    if (speed.trim() === "") {
        speed = 1;
    }

....
```

This is just some sanity check, which ensures that the value of speed is never empty or null. This should pass the edge cases in testing/validation.

```
speed = speed || 1;
```

prevents the code from breaking if nothing is passed on speed

and the `if` condition checks that empty string should not be passed.

To make this even non-breakable, you can check if you can convert `speed` to a valid integer or not. That would be a great fix.

Also, referring to the comments in bugzilla, you could use an external file:

That could probably be done by something like this:

```
var data = self.data;
panel.port.on("changing_now_speed_val", function (speed) {
    var workers = tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile:[data.url('externalFile.js')]
    });
    workers.emit('speedChanged', speed)
}
```

and on your `data/` folder in your addon, create a file `externalFile.js` which should contain something like this:

```
self.port.on('speedChanged', function(speed){
    speed = speed || 1;
    speed = speed.trim() === "" ? 1 : speed; //little ternary trick
    document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate='+speed + ';';
}
```

I think this explains something. Please comment me back if you have any questions! Happy addon-ing!